# passing my "own" map from controller and render it in view

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, gsp, grails-controller

So this is my show() method in my controller with InsitutionList as a global variable but when I want to access this InsitutionList from list.gsp it is not rendering (also not giving any errors like null value, from there I believe i am passing it successfully) anything. Also mentioning the gsp snippet below.

```
def show(Long id){
    def tacticalIndustryCodeInstance = TacticalIndustryCode.get(id);
    def query = Institution.where { idParam ->
        idInstitution == idParam    
    }   
    def institution = query.find(id)
    if(!institution){
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'institution.label', default: 'Institution'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    institutionList.putAt(institution.getLongName(), tacticalIndustryCodeInstance)

    if(!tacticalIndustryCodeInstance){
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'tacticalIndustryCode.label', default: 'TacticalIndustryCode'), id])        
        redirect(action: "list")
        return 
    }       
    [tacticalIndustryCodeInstance: tacticalIndustryCodeInstance, institutionList: institutionList]

}
```

tried different things, no luck:

1)

```
                    <td><g:link action="show" id="${tacticalIndustryCodeInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: tacticalIndustryCodeInstance, field: "id")}</g:link></td>

                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: tacticalIndustryCodeInstance, field: "industrySector")}</td>

                    <td>${Institution.executeQuery("Select longName from Institution where idInstitution = :id?",[id : $(fieldValue(bean: tacticalIndustryCodeInstance, field: "id"))])}</td>   
                </tr>
            </g:each>
```

2) Even simpler like this also not working

```
            <g:each in="${institutionList}" var="institutionListInstance">
                <td>${fieldValue(bean: institutionList, field: "longName")}</td>
            </g:each>
```

3)

```
<table id="tacticalIndustryCodeTable" class="center">
<thead>
                    <tr>                    
                        <g:sortableColumn property="id" title="${message(code: 'tacticalIndustryCode.id.label', default: 'Institution Id')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="industrySector" title="${message(code: 'tacticalIndustryCode.industrySector.label', default: 'industrySector')}" />

                        <g:sortableColumn property="longName" title="${message(code: 'institution.longName.label', default: 'longName')}" />

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <g:each in="${institutionList}" var="institutionListInstance">
                    <td>${institutionListInstance.key}</td>
                    <g:each in="${institutionListInstance.value}" var="item">
                        <td>${item.id}</td>
                        <td>${item.industrysector}</td>
                </g:each>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're changing wrong action or gsp. As soon as you haven't specified view in "show" action Grails will render show.gsp but you expecting "institutionList" on the list.gsp.

Comment: I believe that's not the case as I can edit views from there....I believe it is with my gsp...I posted my detailed gsp table in option 3 in the original question....

Comment: I agree with Sergei. Your controller code doesn't show any redirect or render to `list.gsp with` a model containing `institutionList`. Have you tried a `render(view: "list", model: [tacticalIndustryCodeInstance: tacticalIndustryCodeInstance, institutionList: institutionList])` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `institutionList` is a `Map` not a `List`

```
institutionList.putAt(institution.getLongName(), tacticalIndustryCodeInstance)
```

looks like

```
Map.putAt(Object key, Object value)
```

What displays the gsp with following code ?

```
<g:each in="${institutionList}" var="institutionListInstance">
    <td>${institutionListInstance}</td>
</g:each>
```

or with the simplest code in the gsp ?

```
<h1>${institutionList}</h1>
```

Comment: Hi Isammoc...thanks for replying....I tried that before to just pass it as List...but that did not work..both of the options are not rendering anything...I tried other options like 1)Do a GORM query from gsp...2)Tried with different datatypes in the map...3)tried with encodeAsHTML() for properties...no luck.....I think it is something wrong I am doing with the gsp.......I am posting my more of my gsp below....

Comment: I posted my gsp in the original question as option 3

Comment: What result do you have ? Why `institutionList` is global ? Did you tried to `println` or `log` your variable in the controller ?